# usb drives not detected after fresh install ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: usb, detect

I've made a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04.1 and I'm unable to detect usb drives.. no idea why.

This is the ouptup of lsusb while I have a usb drive connected.

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04ca:3018 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5a01 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 24ae:1100  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have no idea how this happened or how to fix it, can anybody help?
Thanks for the effort.

---

### UPDATE

Both usb devices and external hard drives ( mass storage usb device) were not detected....

I have done a fresh install again , now usb devices are detected except for the external hard drive that is detected only through USB 2.0 port and not detected from the USB 3.0 port.

Earlier with the original ubuntu install I had done it was detected on the usb 3.0 port also.

I must add the fact that the usb device is in NTFS filesystem.
Also the laptop is booting in UEFI mode , I have disabled legacy bios support in order to make an UEFI ubuntu install.

---

### UPDATE

I have run the command `sudo /usr/sbin/update-usbids` but the external hard drive is not detected through usb 3.0 only 2.0...

---

### UPDATE

I have no idea what happened... now the external hdd is detected also through usb 3.0 also when I boot in uefi and legacy bios.
I'll try to see if uefi secure boot is causing the problem...

---

### UPDATE

Even with uefi secure boot it works....
It is a mistery to me what was the cause for the problem.
Can anyone help determine the source of the problem?

Thanks for the time

Comment: All USB devices or mass storage devices only? Also please update with your hardware specs.

Comment: Were the usb devices working with an earlier install ? Can you run this command : sudo /usr/sbin/update-usbids and then reboot ? Does your BIOS have options for legacy usb ?

Comment: Celtic warrior can you give me a terminal command that will give me the hardware specs of the external hard drive?